# How To Get A Changing Amount of Number Inputs From A User

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, math, calculator

I am trying to make a simple calculator, and I was wondering how to let the user enter the amount of numbers he/she wants.  E.g. they could say, 5*7, or they could add another number to the equation, 5*7+6.  So, my question is, can there be variables on standby if the user decides to make a bigger equation, but not do anything if they don't want extra integers?  I have searched on StackOverflow and the Internet but I haven't found anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guys! You should post some comments when you down vote! otherwise fresh users like these would have no idea what they are doing wrong!

Comment: Please spend two or three minutes going though Stackoverflow Tour first http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I've wanted to say that, but I also didn't want to get band.  Thanks for helping me voice out my problems!

Comment: I don't think this user has done *anything* wrong. There is a well defined question supported by an example application. The remedy of ignorance is the point of this site, though the way some of you behave one might think the point was badge collecting self aggrandisement.

Comment: You're welcome, but I just see this as my duty as I've also been there once. My best guess is that you have been down voted because you haven't said anything clearly about what you have done so far. "Show your work" is one of the important rules here. I can't see any other reason.

Comment: All my questions are well thought out, in my opinion.  If another user asks virtually the same thing, but with worse grammar, they get voted up while I go down.  And I just started learning this language, that is why I am ignorant.

Comment: Also please note that the question title may be misleading. Your problem at hand is more about expression parsing than "taking variable number of inputs" for which you could have easily found an answer if you did some initial research on your favorite search engine.

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure how to state myy question in the title.  I did some research but since I didn't know what it would be called, I wasn't sure what to look fot.

Comment: Ignorance is greatly underrated -- it is the beginning of understanding.

Comment: That sounded like a wise saying! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure for an arbitrary number of instances of some type is a List or Collection. These are themselves classes. One type of collection frequently used for storing expression trees (which is what you're doing) is Stack.

I think you need to do some reading before you go any further. I'd search Bing or google for parsers, lexers and expression trees.